# Fitting parameters in a pipeline: pipeline.set_params() vs **params inside estimator

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline, hyperparameters

I am wondering what passing `**params` into the final estimator of a pipeline does compared to `pipeline.set_params(**params)` and what is the proper way to pass hyperparameters in the estimator of a pipeline.

**1#** In the following code snipet:

```py
state = 66

params ={
'regressor__max_depth' : 10,
'regressor__num_leaves' : 320,
'regressor__bagging_fraction' : 0.7,
'regressor__feature_fraction' : 0.6,
'regressor__min_child_weight' : 23.35,
'regressor__min_split_gain' : 0.04268,
'regressor__metric' : 'mae',
'regressor__n_estimators': 1000,
'regressor__random_state': state
}

# Pipeline with standard scaling and the regressor
regressors = [lgb.LGBMRegressor()]
for reg in regressors:
    steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor), ('regressor', reg)]
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

pipeline.set_params(**params)

#fitting of lgbm model

for fold_, (trn_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(folds.split(X_train.values, y_train.values)):
        print("fold n°{}".format(fold_))
        eval_set = [(X_train.iloc[trn_idx], y_train.iloc[trn_idx]), (X_train.iloc[val_idx], y_train.iloc[val_idx])]

        lgb_m = pipeline.fit(X= X_train.iloc[trn_idx], y= y_train.iloc[trn_idx], regressor__eval_set=eval_set,
                          regressor__early_stopping_rounds=100, regressor__verbose = 10)

        fold_pred[val_idx] = lgb_m.predict(X_train.iloc[val_idx], num_iteration=lgb_m.steps[1][1].best_iteration_)

#deal with feature importance

        fold_importance_df = pd.DataFrame()
        fold_importance_df["feature"] = X_train.columns
        fold_importance_df["importance"] = lgb_m.steps[1][1].feature_importances_
        fold_importance_df["fold"] = fold_ + 1
        feature_importance_df = pd.concat([feature_importance_df, fold_importance_df], axis=0)

        lgb_preds += lgb_m.predict(X_test, num_iteration=lgb_m.steps[1][1].best_iteration_) / (nfolds * nrepeats)

    print("CV score: {:<8.5f}".format(np.sqrt(mean_absolute_error(fold_pred, y_train))))
```

I get different CV score depending on `params`, as intended (I do not touch `state`).

The output of `pipeline.steps[1]` is:

```
('regressor',
 LGBMRegressor(bagging_fraction=0.7, boosting_type='gbdt', class_weight=None,
        colsample_bytree=1.0, feature_fraction=0.6, importance_type='split',
        learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=10, metric='mae', min_child_samples=20,
        min_child_weight=23.35, min_split_gain=0.04268, n_estimators=1000,
        n_jobs=-1, num_leaves=320, objective=None, random_state=66,
        reg_alpha=0.0, reg_lambda=0.0, silent=True, subsample=1.0,
        subsample_for_bin=200000, subsample_freq=0))
```

**2#** However, if I do:

```py
# Pipeline with standard scaling and the regressor
regressors = [lgb.LGBMRegressor(**params)]
for reg in regressors:
    steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor), ('regressor', reg)]
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

#pipeline.set_params(**params)
```

and comment out `.set_params()`instead, my hyperparamters do not seem to influence the CV score.

In this case the output of `pipeline.steps[1]` is slightly different:

```
('regressor',
 LGBMRegressor(boosting_type='gbdt', class_weight=None, colsample_bytree=1.0,
        importance_type='split', learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=-1,
        min_child_samples=20, min_child_weight=0.001, min_split_gain=0.0,
        n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, num_leaves=31, objective=None,
        random_state=None, reg_alpha=0.0, reg_lambda=0.0,
        regressor__bagging_fraction=0.7, regressor__feature_fraction=0.6,
        regressor__max_depth=10, regressor__metric='mae',
        regressor__min_child_weight=23.35,
        regressor__min_split_gain=0.04268, regressor__n_estimators=1000,
        regressor__num_leaves=320, regressor__random_state=66, silent=True,
        subsample=1.0, subsample_for_bin=200000, subsample_freq=0))
```

I have also tried to pass `**params` to `lgb_m = pipeline.fit()` as you would for `lgb.train()` but I get a TypeError then.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here? Why do #1 seem to work as intended but not #2? Why can't I simply pass my paramters to `.fit()`? And what is the most correct option?

Comment: Oh... I guess it is just ```regressor__``` in my params that mess things up, uh?

Still strange that I do not get some kind of TypeError from it. Nonetheless, is one way more correct than the other and what are the implications?